# Media query problems w/ Picture tag on Firefox Android

Tags: android, html, css, image, firefox

I've been using the  tag to switch between images depending on the media query. It works fine on Chrome on my Note 3, but on Firefox I've been having troubles. Let's say I have this code:

```
<picture class="thumb-set">
  <source media="(min-width: 1200px)" srcset="http://placehold.it/360x202">     
  <source media="(min-width: 992px)" srcset="http://placehold.it/294x165">
  <source media="(min-width: 768px)" srcset="http://placehold.it/345x194">
  <source media="(min-width: 480px)" srcset="http://placehold.it/210x118">
  <source media="(max-width: 479px)" srcset="http://placehold.it/290x163">   
  <img src="http://placehold.it/360x202">
</picture>
```

Firefox will correctly show whatever CSS I have for the min-width: 480px. However, it just constantly INSISTS on showing the picture source I have selected for min-width: 768px.

Anyone has an idea why?

Comment: Have you tried picturefill 3.0 (https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill/tree/3.0/dist)?

Comment: Yea, I'm running it. Modernizr too.

Comment: Are you sure you use pf 3.0 and not pf 2.0? see also: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1178106, https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill/tree/3.0/src/plugins/gecko-picture, https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill/tree/master/dist

Comment: Ohyou're right Alexander, I'm using picturefill 2.3.1 instead of 3. Since it was in beta, I didn't dare use it. It works! Thank you so much.
For the record, a max-width did not solve the problem.